# Bind datatable to datagrid

Tags: wpf

I made a code below to bind datatable to datagrid with dynamic columns which number depends on enduser's decision.  it creates correct number of columns and rows with headers.  but the problem is each cell does not show anything (empty cells).  Could you advise me what the problem is in the code below?  I really appreciate your help.

```
       string[] filenames;

        filenames = read.Filenames;

        DataTable tvsa = new DataTable();

        for (int i = 0; i < filenames.Length; i++)
        {

            double[] a_raw = arsconv.Ama;

            // Define the columns of the table.
            DataColumn column= new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double");
            column.ColumnName = filenames[i];
            tvsa.Columns.Add(column);

            //Define rows
            DataRow dr;
            for (int l = 0; l < a_raw.Length; l++)
            {
                dr = tvsa.NewRow();
                dr[filenames[i]] = a_raw[l];
                tvsa.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }

        datagrid_accu.ItemsSource = tvsa.DefaultView;
```

XAML:

```
                <DataGrid Name="datagrid_accu" ItemsSource="{Binding tvsa.DefaultView}" Width="Auto"   AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: What would happen if you remove the `ItemsSource="{Binding tvsa.DefaultView}` in XAML ?

Comment: table is created but no values still.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and populated the arrays with some fake data (duh) and it all displayed in the datagrid just fine. Must be something else getting in the way.

Comment: I did but no luck.  Thanks for your suggestion,

Comment: I used to have a filename with fullpath.  After changing it to filename only without paths, I was able to see the values on table.  but another problem was encountered.  extra rows were created.  problem after problem...  Thanks for your help,

Comment: it's always something. it does appear that you would be making more columns than you'd want, but, I don't know what end result you're after. Good luck

Comment: Here is the problem after that problem.  Thanks again,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171779/binding-datatable-to-datagrid-creates-unncessay-rows/21171928#21171928